# A 1-1 correspondence between the equivalent classes of extension of $\mathfrak{g}$-modules $k$ by $M$ with $H^1(\mathfrak{g},M)$.

Tags: lie-algebras, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

This is exercise 7.7.4 of Weibel's an introduction to homological algebra. Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra over a ring $k$. Let $0\to M\xrightarrow{i} N\xrightarrow{\pi} k\to 0$ be a short exact sequence of $\mathfrak{g}$-modules, and $n\in N$ is such that $\pi(n)=1$, define $f:\mathfrak{g}\to M$ by $f(x)=i^{-1}(xn)$.

I have shown that $f$ is a 1-cocycle in the Chevalley-Eilenberg complex $\rm{Hom}(\wedge^*(\mathfrak{g},M))$ and that its class $[f]\in H^1(\mathfrak{g},M)$ does not depend on the choice of $n$. I want to show that the map

$$\left\{\mathrm{equivalent~classes~of~extension~of~k~by~M}\right\}\to H^1(\mathfrak{g},M)$$
$$ (0\to M\xrightarrow{i} N\xrightarrow{\pi} k\to 0) \mapsto [f]$$
gives the 1-1 correspondence. But I'm not able to show that this map is one one and onto.

For ontoness, I am not sure how to construct $N$ and the maps $i$ and $\pi$ to get the exactness of the sequence. Can someone please guide me through the proof or provide any relevant hints or resources?

Comment: See my [lecture notes](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_76_coho.pdf), Theorem 4.2.6. It has a detailed proof (in your notation, take $B=k$).